# Bad prediction for ARIMA timeseries

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, arima

I am trying to use ARIMA for hotel reservation. I have data for a year each day and I want to make predictions.
But, my result is very poor I wonder why.
Here I attach my data
[image: hotel data]

And, this is how I run my model
[image: model]

I got that the best order parameter is 212. with AIC score 3460.847 *I also wonder why its so high.

And, this is my result. orange color
[image]

I have data from 280 days and want to predict 70 days. as depicted in the graph, the prediction is showing only around 170-180. So far from reality. How can I improve my model ?